# How to loop through radiobuttonlist in asp.net (c#) using Foreach loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, foreach

I'm trying to use foreach loop to loop through a radiobuttonlist, but it doesn't work. Here are my codes:

```
foreach (ListItem itemp in rbtnsizeprice.Items )
{    
    itemprice = double.Parse(itemp.Selected.ToString());               
}
```

The error displayed is:

> Input string was not in correct format

Anyone has a clue what's wrong?

Comment: what is the value of "itemp.Selected.ToString()" ?

Comment: Please post `ListItem` type. Maybe you want to parse `Value` property?

Comment: I have 3 options for this radiobuttonlist. The values are: 3, 4.5 and 4

Comment: I tried parsing value property but there was the same error as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If itemp.Selected.ToString() is null or not a number (I think it is a boolean), you won't be able to parse it to a double.  Use a TryParse(), but you need to get the item value.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much